# Java - get convert xml string (soap) to java object

Tags: java, xml

I am using Spring Boot and Java 11.

The following SAOP Response has a list of `HotelStays`.  How do I get the list of `HotelStay` object?

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:awsse="http://xml.xxxx.com/2010/06/Session_v3" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
   <soap:Header>
      <wsa:To>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa:To>
      <wsa:From>
         <wsa:Address>https://nodeD2.production.webservices.xxxx.com/XXXX</wsa:Address>
      </wsa:From>
      <wsa:Action>http://webservices.xxxx.com/Hotel_MultiSingleAvailability_10.0</wsa:Action>
      <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:xxxx</wsa:MessageID>
      <wsa:RelatesTo RelationshipType="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/reply">XXXX</wsa:RelatesTo>
      <awsse:Session TransactionStatusCode="End">
         <awsse:SessionId>xxxx</awsse:SessionId>
         <awsse:SequenceNumber>1</awsse:SequenceNumber>
         <awsse:SecurityToken>XXXX</awsse:SecurityToken>
      </awsse:Session>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <OTA_HotelAvailRS xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05 OTA_HotelAvailRS.xsd" EchoToken="MultiSingle" Version="6.001" PrimaryLangID="EN">
         <Success />
         <Warnings>
            <Warning Type="3" Status="PRV.40" Tag="CLS" />
            <Warning Type="3" Status="PRV.56" Tag="OK" />
         </Warnings>
         <HotelStays>
            <HotelStay RoomStayRPH="0 1 2 3 4 5 6">
               <BasicPropertyInfo ChainCode="BK" HotelCode="BKDURB3H" HotelCityCode="DUR" HotelName="BAYSIDE HOTEL &amp; SELF CATERING 110 WEST S" HotelCodeContext="1A" ChainName="BOOKING.COM" AreaID="4" HotelSegmentCategoryCode="16" SupplierIntegrationLevel="3">
                  <Position Latitude="-2985829" Longitude="3102385" />
                  <Address>
                     <AddressLine>110 DOCTOR PIXLEY KASEME STREET (WEST STREET)STREET</AddressLine>
                     <CityName>DURBAN</CityName>
                     <PostalCode>4001</PostalCode>
                     <CountryName Code="ZA" />
                  </Address>
                  <Award Provider="LSR" Rating="2" />
                  <RelativePosition Direction="E" Distance="0.2" UnitOfMeasureCode="2">
                     <Transportations>
                        <Transportation TransportationCode="20" />
                     </Transportations>
                  </RelativePosition>
               </BasicPropertyInfo>
            </HotelStay>
            <HotelStay RoomStayRPH="7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28">
               <BasicPropertyInfo ChainCode="BK" HotelCode="BKDURB34" HotelCityCode="DUR" HotelName="DURBAN MANOR HOTEL AND CONFERENCE CENTRE" HotelCodeContext="1A" ChainName="BOOKING.COM" AreaID="4" HotelSegmentCategoryCode="16" SupplierIntegrationLevel="3">
                  <Position Latitude="-2986047" Longitude="3102419" />
                  <Address>
                     <AddressLine>1 DURBAN CLUB PLACE</AddressLine>
                     <CityName>DURBAN</CityName>
                     <PostalCode>4000</PostalCode>
                     <CountryName Code="ZA" />
                  </Address>
                  <Award Provider="LSR" Rating="3" />
                  <RelativePosition Direction="E" Distance="0.3" UnitOfMeasureCode="2">
                     <Transportations>
                        <Transportation TransportationCode="20" />
                     </Transportations>
                  </RelativePosition>
               </BasicPropertyInfo>
            </HotelStay>
         </HotelStays>
      </OTA_HotelAvailRS>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

When I try create a `Document` it is always empty (`[#document: null]`):

```
public static Document getDocument(final String soapMessage) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is = new InputSource();
    is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(soapMessage));
    Document doc = db.parse(is);
    return doc;
}
```